# If I install a ColdFusion MVC framework, will it mess up old applications?

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, coldfusion, coldbox

The title pretty much explains the meat of the question. I'm debating on starting **new** development using MVC and the Coldbox Framework (or possibly another), but I'm not sure if the old applications that **do not** use the framework will work properly.

The way things are setup, I do not want to go back and redesign the old applications on the server to MVC. There are just too many and they are just too large. I do however, want to work on all new development (not application extensions) utilizing the MVC architecture.

Server runs on ColdFusion 9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most mvc framework will use a front controller, e.g. `index.cfm?event=x.y`, so at least you'll need to change all the `href`, unless you're also doing URL rewrite, otherwise your SEO will tank.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So CF MVC uses event controllers like you showed? (I kind of figured that, but haven't got too deep in it just yet) Let me give you some more background. It's an Intranet site, so SEO is meaningless. There are multiple apps contained on a single server, each are different from the others and each is self contained. Would I still need to change all the href if CF MVC works with a url param? To me, it doesn't seem like it would effect the already existing applications. I just wanted to find out if old apps would still work before getting too deep into CF MVC.

Comment: the action URL of a form post, for example, would be changed to things like `index.cfm?event=someEntity.save`.  So you will need to make sure all those are taken care of in the View layer.  Then slowly move logics into the controller layer, then to model layer.